# How can I find billingAccountId in Azure

Tags: azure, billing

In order to get Balances in Azure Consumption API I have to find BillingAccountId first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/balances/getbybillingaccount

I've tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-view-all-accounts but that number doesn't seem to be a BillingAccountId cause every time I send requests to get balances data it sends me an error (the same if I use any other fake number)

Answer (score 2):

Cost Management + Billing is the correct place, but you need to go to 'Properties', not Overview

Answer (score -2):

Cost Management + Billing is the correct place. Check the **Overview** section to find the BillingAccountID.

Comment: The overview page does not have the billing account ID.

Comment: The overview section does not have the billing account ID,